# Passing a Date variable in a Openrowset query

Tags: sql-server

I have this Openrowset Query where I'm able to pass a Path to get the correct Excel file. I can't figure out the exact number of quotes and/or the type conversion

I need to pass a `WHERE` statement to get a specific date in the table. I'm coming from VBA where you put 2 quotes and 2 & and you're all set. It seems SQL needs hundreds of them! (If someone has a link to an online university about SQL quotes that'd be much appreciated too)

```
set @sql1 = 'select * 
             FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
                      ''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @filePath1 + '' + ';' + '''' + ',
             ''Select * from [Sheet1$] '''+')' 

exec(@sql1)
```

I'd like to add `WHERE DATE = @PnLDate`

Answer (score 0):

The rule is very similar to what you know but it applies to single quote `'`. When you want one of them inside a string you **escape** it using two `''`. Apart of them, you must have one for openning and one for closing.

The string you show, is a bit complicated just because it contains innecesary empty strings, and secuentialy contatenated stirngs that can be replaced just for only one resultant string.  Below a simiplificated version of your string:

```
set @sql1 = 'select * 
         FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
             ''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @filePath1 + ';'',
             ''Select * from [Sheet1$] '')'
```

With your requested `where` may be:

```
DECLARE @PnLDate datetime     -- may be varchar instead, if so, must remove convert(....) and use straight @PnLDate
set @PnLDate = '2014/08/01'

set @sql1 = 'select * 
         FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
             ''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @filePath1 + ';'',
             ''Select * from [Sheet1$] where DATE = #'+     -- hash #  is MS Access delimiter for dates
             convert(varchar(25), @PnLDate, 111) 
             +'#'')'                                        -- results in #2014/08/01#
```

Be warned that when you use "dynamic SQL" your data can inject malicious code on the string.  read about [sql Injection](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)

Comment: using this method :


`
set @PnLDate = convert(nvarchar(max),@PnLDate)
set @sql1 = 'select * 
         FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
             ''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @filePath1 + ';'',
             ''Select * from [Sheet1$] WHERE DDate = ' + @PnLDate + ' '')'
`


I get this error:

The data types nvarchar(max) and date are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: the error comes form that @PnLDate need to be converted to a string to be contenated. (there are only few things that SQL server automaticaly concatenetes conveting its types, datetime is not one.).  Also notice, that the resultant string must be a valid sql sentence. The one that may result in your case shoud read as `DDate = 12/31/2015` missing the necesary quotes around the date constant.  See the convert in my edited example and the added quotes to sorround

Comment: thank you very much for your help but I have no luck with this
I change the type for `DECLARE @PnLDate varchar(25)`
Then I set the variable like this: 
`set @PnLDate = 08/01/2014`
Then I used your query and I get this:
_
Cannot execute the query "Select * from [Sheet1$] where DATE = "08-01-2014"" against OLE DB provider

I also tried to remove the double quotes and it still does not work

Comment: If I use the numeric value of the date I can have it work like this:

`set @sql1 = 'select DCLOSE 
      FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
         ''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @filePath1 + ';'',
         ''Select * from [Sheet1$] WHERE DDate = ' + convert(nvarchar(max),41850) + ''')'`

Comment: I just can't replace that numeric value by a date in a variable

Comment: I think we're getting closer, but some quotes (again!) after 2014# seems to be the problem now.    I get this error:
Cannot execute the query "Select * from [Sheet1$] where DATE = #08/01/2014#" against OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: Since I can't pass a date, I created a table giving the excel serial number for each date and I pass the serial number in Openrowset. Not most efficient but that works

Comment: in sql server you can obtain the serial of a date just with a convert: `convert(mydate as real)` or as INT. Serial dates on sql server differs on 2 units from VBA serial dates. so you must add or substract 2 after convert (I don't remember now). But I am still sure that if you can contatenate `#08/01/2014#` it will work.  Glad to help