# Getting 'Attribute "FIELDQUOTE" could not be specified for this type' when using .xml format file for a T-SQL OPENROWSET BULK Query

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, bcp, openrowset

I am getting an 'Attribute "FIELDQUOTE" could not be specified for this type.' that has me pulling my hair out trying to perform an OPENROWSET query to work so I can bulk import records from a .csv file.

I've tried to simplify things to narrow down where my issue might be coming from but am still at a loss.

My SQL Server query is simple:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempMines (
MINE_ID NVARCHAR(10),
COAL_METAL_IND int,
CURRENT_MINE_TYPE DEC(5,2),
CURRENT_MINE_STATUS NVARCHAR(5),
CURRENT_STATUS_DT DATE);

INSERT INTO #TempMines (MINE_ID, COAL_METAL_IND, CURRENT_MINE_TYPE, CURRENT_MINE_STATUS, CURRENT_STATUS_DT)
SELECT MINE_ID, COAL_METAL_IND, CURRENT_MINE_TYPE, CURRENT_MINE_STATUS, CURRENT_STATUS_DT
FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'C:\sqlStuff\sampleData.csv',
    FORMATFILE = 'C:\sqlStuff\sampleFormat.xml'
) AS TempMinesData;
```

Therefore my .xml format file is also strait forward:

```
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <RECORD>
    <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="12" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" FIELDQUOTE='"'/>
    <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="12" FIELDQUOTE='"'/>
    <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="12" FIELDQUOTE='"'/>
    <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="7" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" FIELDQUOTE='"'/>
    <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="12" FIELDQUOTE='"'/>
  </RECORD>
  <ROW>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="MINE_ID" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="COAL_METAL_IND" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="CURRENT_MINE_TYPE" xsi:type="SQLDECIMAL" PRECISION="5" SCALE="2"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="CURRENT_MINE_STATUS" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="CURRENT_STATUS_DT" xsi:type="SQLDATE"/>
  </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

It's just a local host database. I've double checked my permissions for the directory and individual .xml and .csv files, and am running SSMS as an admin. [image: File Permissions]

[image: File Permission too]

Additionally I've double checked to make sure my line endings are consistent with my the settings in my .xml file
[image: line endings]

However, no matter what I do I seem to come back to this error and am not sure what the cause could possibly be.

[image: Error]

This seems like such a simple task! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe sql server doesn't like that your integer column has quotes. What happens if you change the datatypes of your quoted fields to nvarchar in the xml file?

Comment: You have a DATE and need to convert the string to a Date Type. See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431546/passing-a-date-variable-in-a-openrowset-query

Comment: I don't actually see FIELDQUOTE as a specified option for XML format files. Maybe I'm just missing something: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/xml-format-files-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#AttrOfFieldElement

Comment: It's also not present in [the XSD](https://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format/bulkloadschema.xsd). Where did you get the idea to use `FIELDQUOTE`? Do you have a different example where this attribute works?